# Помогите с тестом!

Tags: python

Напиши функцію `calculate_profit`, яка приймає три параметри:
`amount` - початкова сума, яку ми кладемо на депозит;
`percent` - річна відсоткова ставка;
`period` - кількість років (час, на який гроші кладуться на депозит).
Функція повинна розрахувати і повернути суму чистого прибутку за весь час.

Приклади (ми перевіряємо тільки цілу частину):

```
calculate_profit(1000, 5, 1) == 50
calculate_profit(12500, 3, 12) == 5322
```

Мой код:

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: float, period: int) -> float:
    totalAmount = amount  
    years =  0 
    while ( years < period): 
        totalAmount = (amount * percent // 100 )
        years += 1
        return totalAmount
```

Подскажите что у меня не правильно, пожалуйста!:)

Comment: Почему вы решили, что у вас что-то не правильно?

Comment: тест дальше не пропускає

Comment: Function 'calculate_profit' should return 0 when period is 0

Comment: вибиває цю помилку

Comment: @andreymal потому что return на неправильном отступе, и к целому приводить, возможно, нужно только окончательный результат

Answer (score 1):

Судя по примерам, считаются сложные проценты

Приводить к целым следует только в конце, иначе результат не совпадает

А ну да, выходить из функции внутри цикла - бессмыслено

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: float, period: int) -> float:
    totalAmount = amount
    for _ in range(period):
        totalAmount += (totalAmount * percent / 100 )
    return int(totalAmount - amount)
```

Comment: Дякую! Дуже допомогли! ( :